# "web3.eth.accounts" doesn't output account address

Tags: web3js

I follow the instruction video "Code Your Own Cryptocurrency on Ethereum (Full)" from Dapp University on youtube. What is different when i use web3.eth.account.

Here is from tutorial

[image]

Here was i do it my self (it's doesn't give me some address):

[image]

Comment: using `ganache-cli`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the video is quite old it is possible that the video was made when web3 was still around version `0.20.0` for which the function effectively retrieved the accounts list.

Since then web3 is on version `1.0.0-beta.x` for which you'll need to call `web3.eth.getAccounts()` method to retrieve the list of accounts.

see the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=getAccounts#getaccounts)